# Change views inside NSSplitViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssplitview

I'm trying to migrate my Objective-C and now improving Swift knowledge to an application for Mac OS X. Steep learning curve!

I'm trying to load a `NSSplitViewController` with different views in the "detail view" depending on buttons pressed on the "master view" if you will. Following tutorials and searching for hours has led me to nothing.

I currently have:

```
import Cocoa

class MainSplitView: NSSplitViewController, BlissWindowDelegate {

    var masterViewController: vcMainMenu {
        let masterItem = splitViewItems[0] as! NSSplitViewItem
        return masterItem.viewController as! vcMainMenu
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        masterViewController.delegate = self

    }

    func userDidSelectFunction(function: String) {

        switch function {
        case "app":
            println("You have selected to load the appointment screen")
        case "cust":
            println("You have selected to load the customer screen")
        case "login":
            println("I think I am here and you've clicked login?")
            let detailItem = splitViewItems[1] as! NSSplitViewItem

            // Trying to load the views here ... but no idea how to

        case "admin":
            println("You've clicked admin")
        default:
            println("Nothing here ...")

        }

    }

}
```

I'm using `BlissWindowDelegate` to tell me which button was pressed. I am then trying to load into the `splitViewItem[1]` various views from a Storyboard. But having no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Even for a decent reference? Nothing on Google is seeming to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it sounds like you have a specific set of detail panes that can be shown, using an `NSTabViewController` is probably best way to accomplish this.

Basically, your `NSSplitViewController` has two children: the master view controller, and a `NSTabViewController`. And the tab view controller has its own children for each of the detail panes. Since tab view controller shouldn't present its own tab selection UI (the master pane is doing that), you would set the `tabStyle` to be `.Unspecified`. The storyboard would look something like this:

[image: Storyboard with NSSplitViewController and NSTabViewController]

Your `MainSplitViewController` would also have a reference to the tab view controller, `detailController`. Then on `userDidSelectFunction()`, you would set the detailController's `selectedTabViewItemIndex` to be that of the corresponding detail pane. `NSTabViewController` will take care of the view transition, including animating between the panes if setup to do so.

Comment: Thanks so much for the ideas. It's a great solution and I'll give it a look. Thanks for taking the time in responding.

Comment: How does the `MainSplitViewController` have a reference to the `detailController`? Doesn't it only know about the `NSSplitItem` that holds the `detailController`?

Comment: Figured it out. From within my master/menu view controller, I used `parent?.childViewControllers[1] as! NSTabViewController!` to get a reference to the tabs.

Comment: `let tabView = parent?.children[1] as? NSTabViewController?`  
`tabView??.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 1`  
Just an update on syntax.