# MacOS menu in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsapplication

I am looking to create a menu sidebar in my application which can display and control view controllers besides the menu. Something like the following:
[image: Target User Interface]
I would like to avoid a TableView for the menu, but I'm not totally against it. I've tried using a TableView and a Container, and a TabViewController but I can't seem to get either to look like the above.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/sidebars/

Comment: What you are looking for is called NSSplitViewController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssplitviewcontroller

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks very much, got a working NSTabViewController and paired it with the SplitViewController; exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspiration comes from "What you are looking for is called NSSplitViewController"

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720730/change-views-inside-nssplitviewcontroller]

Code is as follows:

```
class MenuController: NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        tabViewController = parent?.childViewControllers[1] as! NSTabViewController! //The parent is the SplitView, so the child in the second view would be the TabViewController
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var SecondButton: NSButton!

    var tabViewController = NSTabViewController()

    @IBAction func FirstView(_ sender: Any) {
        tabViewController?.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 0 //Now that the TabViewController is specified, one may set the current view controller within the tabview.
    }

    @IBAction func SecondView(_ sender: Any) {
        tabViewController?.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 1 //Shows the second view in NSTabViewController
    }
}
```

In the diagram, the `NSSplitViewController` has two `childViewControllers`; therefore it is the parent of those controllers and can be accessed via the `parent?` method in both child view controllers. Once you've specified the `tabViewController`, you can then set its `selectedTabViewItemIndex[value]` which switches the view in the `NSTabViewController`.